# timezone format err in google calendar API

Tags: go, timezone, google-calendar-api, timezone-offset, rfc3339

```
input = append(input, strings.TrimSpace(sessions[uuid]["nameStage"].(string)))
input = append(input, strings.TrimSpace(sessions[uuid]["startDateStage"].(string))+"T"+strings.TrimSpace(sessions[uuid]["startTimeStage"].(string))+"+02:00")
input = append(input, strings.TrimSpace(sessions[uuid]["endDateStage"].(string))+"T"+strings.TrimSpace(sessions[uuid]["endTimeStage"].(string))+"+02:00")


func createEvent(input []string, tok *oauth2.Token) string {

    client := conf.Client(oauth2.NoContext, tok)
    calendarService, _ := calendar.New(client)
    event := new(calendar.Event)

    // set calendar values

    event.Summary = input[0]
    startTime := new(calendar.EventDateTime)
    startTime.DateTime = input[1]
    event.Start = startTime

    endTime := new(calendar.EventDateTime)
    endTime.DateTime = input[2]
    event.End = endTime
_, err := calendarService.Events.Insert("primary", event).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return "Cannot create event"
    }

    return "Done successfully"
}
```

this is  a part of my code I use to create event using google calendar API 
.the code is written in go.
the code takes the name and the time values from the session and puts it in array and sends it to createEvent
sometimes the code runs correctly and sometimes it gives me an error

```
googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for: Invalid format: "2018-00-18T22:08:00+02:00" is malformed at "+02:00", invalid
```

I use "+02:00" to make timezone Cairo/Egypt

Comment: It looks like it's more broken at the month part than the UTC offset...

Comment: is it one based of zero-based in the month part

Comment: It should be 1-based in ISO-8601 format. Basically that looks like a broken date to me.

Comment: ok thanks I thought it was zero based